# Is it true that power series with infinite radius of convergence are at most exponential?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Suppose I have a real power series $P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/a_n$ with $a_n>0$ which has infinite radius of convergence (ROC). Is it true that I can find constant $c>0$ such that $|P(x)|\leq e^{c(1+|x|)}$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$?

The answer is obviously true if we consider the exponential power series. In a sense, is the exponential power series the "worst possible" power series with infinite ROC?

All I have been able to say till now is that $a_n^{1/n}\to 0$ if the ROC is infinite. So given any $x$, I can say there exists $N_x\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_n>(2|x|)^n$ for all $n>N_x$. Hence $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{|x|^n}{a_n}\leq\sum_{n=0}^{N_x}\dfrac{|x|^n}{a_n}+\dfrac{1}{2^{N_x}}\leq \sum_{n=0}^{N_x}\dfrac{|x|^n}{a_n}+1$$

Now I need to know (probably) smething about $a_n$ and $N_x$. I am stuck at this point, and any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: An easy counterexample is $P(x)=e^x+e^{x^2}$.

Comment: Daaamn! Somehow I missed this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitely not. Power series with infinite radius of convergence define entire functions (functions which are holomorphic in $\Bbb C$), and conversely every entire function has a Taylor series with infinite radius of convergence.

There are many entire functions with positive Taylor coefficients and super-exponential growth, like $e^{P(z)}$ where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $\ge 2$ and positive coefficients, or $e^{e^z}$.

Here is another way to look at it:
If the Taylor series has positive coefficients and the function satisfies a growth condition $|P(x)|\leq e^{c(1+|x|)}$ then the [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Order_and_type) $\rho(f)$ of $f$ is at most one. But the order can be computed from the coefficients of the Taylor series $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ with
$$
\rho(f) =\limsup_{n\to \infty }{\frac {n\ln n}{-\ln |a_{n}|}}
$$
and that can be made arbitrarily large or infinity, by choosing suitable $a_n$.